# Delphi inspect shows {L at start of all Strings

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-xe2, inspect

I have this issue where if I inspect a string in Delphi it always starts with {L and ends with another }

So for an example, I create a variable *tempStr* that is a string. I do the following code:

```
tempStr := 'hello';
```

When I put a break-point on the next line and stop there to inspect *tempStr* the yellow Delphi inspect window will show

```
{L"he"}
```

This started happening recently, within the last 2 weeks. I was working on protobufs for java to delphi. At first I thought it was happening because I was passing a pointer to a pointer which was filling some of my variables with random characters but I've since moved onto another project with different code and I'm still getting this inspect issue.

Edit: my example was wrong, this issue ends up cutting off the last 3 characters of any of my strings, essentially the amount of characters that the {L  } take up. I have edited the above example to show exactly what I see upon inspection.

As far as Delphi addons go I have: **DDev Extensions 2.83, CodeSiteExpress 5.1, Fast Report 4 and Mad Except 4.0.11**

Comment: This is a known bug in Delphi XE2. Workaround is to completely unregister the C++ debug visualizer package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per **Warren P**'s suggestion I tried completely unregister the C++ debug visualizer package.

In (Tools > Options > Debugger Options > Visualizers) this is:

```
std::string and std::wstring Visualizer for C++
```

After I had this packaged unregistered I noticed that my problem was fixed. I was unsure of exactly what this package all did so I didn't want to leave it disabled. I then restarted Delphi with the package still disabled and upon starting Delphi again I re-enabled the package. Everything seems to be working now and the problem is fixed. So the solution was disable and re-enable this visualizer package.

Comment: Did I do something wrong here? This solved my problem so I put it into an answer. Why am I receiving minus points?

Comment: You don't need this package unless you write C++ code and debug it.  Typically if my comment sorts you out, you would simply write a comment. I have no problem with people writing self-answers but maybe someone felt you should have just left a comment. (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @Arioch'The That's not fair. Warren could have answered. He chose not to. Charles did write an answer. There's no stealing here at all. It takes time to write an answer, more time than a comment. That has value.

Comment: @Arioch Warren did not answer. I can see deleted answers. There are none.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not in need of any points at this point. No need to take offense on my behalf. Charles S is trying to be helpful to future readers here, so that's GOOD.  If disabling and re-enabling has an effect, perhaps it is that the order of the visualizers is changed, causing the problem (the wrong visualizer is stealing focus, so to speak) to go away.

Answer (score 2):

The inspector is simply showing you that the string content is Unicode and not Ansi in nature.  But the fact that it is showing you in C++ syntax makes me think that maybe a custom [Debugger Visualizer](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Debugger_Visualizers) was installed that is overriding the default string inspector.  The default inspector looks like this instead:

[image: inspector]

Go into the Debugger's [Visualizer settings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Visualizers) (Tools > Options > Debugger Options > Visualizers) and check if there are extra visualizers registered and enabled.  The IDE ships with only 3 default visualizers preinstalled:

[image: visualizers]

What you describe sounds like maybe a custom visualizer is manipulating the default inspector text buffer with different characters.

Comment: I didn't make note of this in the original question but it ends up cutting off the last 2 characters of my strings on inspection, it's made inspecting these strings hard without outputting to debug, which gets quite tedious. Also I'm curious as to how I am creating unicode strings rather than ansi. I simply am declaring a variable at the top of my function such as "tempStr : String;" which I've always done. I did use a program called DBGView around the time that it started. That would show debug info when running but nothing to do with inspecting.

Comment: "*I'm curious as to how I am creating unicode strings rather than ansi*" - you did not say which version of Delphi you are using.  `String` is Ansi in Delphi 2007 and earlier, and is Unicode in Delphi 2009 and later.

Comment: I apologize, I am using Delphi XE2. I have colleagues working with the same version that do not see the {L on any of their strings, nor did I until recently.

Comment: Indeed, I would naturally assume this Delphi installation has some sort of add-on.

Comment: Something had to have changed in your IDE environment recently to cause this issue.  By default, the IDE does not display a Unicode string like you claim, so something must be forcing it.

Comment: I have the same 3 visualizers in my (Tools > Options > Debugger Options > Visualizers), I haven't purposely made any changes to the IDE recently, but I agree that something seems like it was changed.

Comment: As far as Delphi addons go I have: DDev Extensions 2.83, CodeSiteExpress 5.1, Fast Report 4 and Mad Except 4.0.11

Answer (score 0):

I too have had this problem not solved by any of the suggestions given.  In a project containing a significant number of packages there were one or two BPLs that would always show in the {L"he"} style.  These packages all had compiler warnings regarding implicitly imported units. Resolving these issues enabled strings to be displayed correctly in the debugger.